# need help reading/parsing TCP network code c++

Tags: c++, networking

i have an application which tracks body movement, it can also act like a server to send the body tracking data out via TCP.
My Client connects to the server and gets the data.

Before the data is send to a client something like this happens :

```
MTBF v10 = bodyPose2MTBF_v10(pose, m_startup, m_stream_position, 1);
ss << v10.get();
m_body_tracking_server->send(ss);
```

where the pose has all the information like position of the head as a vector, leg, shoulder position etc..SS is a new stringstream, and with v10.get() the stream is filled with the pose as a string. In the send method the stringstream(ss) is sent to the client.

In my client i get the stringstream. I also converted it back to mtbf. The problem is, the code is not from me, so i dont understand it all. When the pose is converted to mtbf something like this happens :

```
data.addFlag(0);
data << torso.x() << torso.y() << torso.z();
sensorConfig |= MTBFData_0_4::RightArmPosition;
data.addFlag(1);
.
.
.
```

I get that it is adding a "flag" so that i can recognize the torso for example, followed by the x y and z coordinates of the torso. but the add flag method looks like this :

```
addFlag(unsigned char n)
{
m_flag |= (1i64 << n);
m_buf.replace(7+8, 8, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_flag), 8);
return *this;
}
```

What exactly does this method?? shifting some stuff and reinterpret the char...i really need help to understand this!
thank you!

Comment: Binary operations and arithmetic plays here. You have "binary OR " **single** `|` and left shifting of bits with `<<` **n times**. Unsure about, but `1i64` may be 1 as 64-bit integer ie. `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, dont know if I am right here.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing more code but...

`m_flag |= (1i64 << n);` ... m_flag is probably an unsigned 64 bit int and this is ORing the n<sup>th</sup> bit of m_flag with 1.

`m_buf.replace(7+8, 8, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_flag), 8);` ... now that the flag has been modified, it replaces the current flag value in the buffer with the new flag value.

Answer (score 0):

addFlag is designed to accumulate flags in the m_flag member (some kind of 64 bit integer).  Each call updates a fixed, 8-byte field within m_buf with the latest m_flag value.

m_flag is able to accumulate several flags, each added with separate calls to addFlag.

Keep in mind that the flags in m_flags will accumulate, persisting until some other member function clears it.

Each flag value is associated with a single bit within a 64-bit integer value. This kind of program usually defines a list of possible flag values somewhere, either with a bunch of #define lines or as enums.  Look for values between 0 and 63.